# PHP - Re-arrange multi-array so that certain combinations have the same key(index)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array, which looks like this:

```
Array
(
[sku_0017768] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0f359ce5bf6dc855f160c9b89b4aada0
    )

[sku_0017766] => Array
    (
        [0] => ff5a47bd699bcb52944d0727a5b443b6
        [1] => 0f359ce5bf6dc855f160c9b89b4aada0
    )

[sku_0017723] => Array
    (
        [3] => a3c83832b4089d83d164b3cac596fc7e
    )

[sku_0017767] => Array
    (
        [0] => fb91d14d405be52ce989acd2918ea1a0
    )

[sku_8402350] => Array
    (
        [0] => a3c83832b4089d83d164b3cac596fc7e
        [1] => fb91d14d405be52ce989acd2918ea1a0
        [2] => ff5a47bd699bcb52944d0727a5b443b6
        [3] => d14afce16e477663ebe51fdd65cd5010
    )

[sku_8402200] => Array
    (
        [0] => d14afce16e477663ebe51fdd65cd5010
    )

)
```

Now, this array represents a list of SKU's with one or more 'combination codes'. So, in this example 'sku_0017768' matches product sku_0017766 because they share the same combination code.

sku_8402350 has multiple combination as you can see.

What I need to have now is a new array, where the index(key) of the combination code needs to be same among the other products within the combination.

Output should look like this:

```
Array
(
[sku_0017768] => Array
    (
       [0] => 0f359ce5bf6dc855f160c9b89b4aada0
    )

[sku_0017766] => Array
    (
       [0] => 0f359ce5bf6dc855f160c9b89b4aada0
       [1] => ff5a47bd699bcb52944d0727a5b443b6
    )

[sku_0017723] => Array
    (
       [0] => a3c83832b4089d83d164b3cac596fc7e
    )


[sku_0017767] => Array
    (
       [0] => fb91d14d405be52ce989acd2918ea1a0
    )

[sku_8402350] => Array
    (
       [0] => fb91d14d405be52ce989acd2918ea1a0
       [1] => ff5a47bd699bcb52944d0727a5b443b6
       [2] => d14afce16e477663ebe51fdd65cd5010
       [3] => a3c83832b4089d83d164b3cac596fc7e
    )

[sku_8402200] => Array
    (
       [2] => d14afce16e477663ebe51fdd65cd5010
    )
)
```

The difficulty I have is that when a key is already in use, the key of the other products within the combination should increase (with 1) as well, until there is an empty key which the combination can use.

Can anybody help me pointing me in the right direction? Feel free to ask if anything is not clear.

Comment: Well, what about simply *sorting* all of those keys?  Otherwise, you need some kind of heuristic that can chooae the "correct" position of each key ... with the distinct possibility that there will be no such place.  *(e.g.* one of the SKU's doesn't have that many keys.)

Comment: It occurs to me that perhaps this is an "XY problem."  Perhaps you could create a second, "inverted index" array.  The key to this array is "the key," and the contents is a list (array) of records which contain `[sku_number, position]`.  This would relieve you of the (possibly, "impossible to achieve") requirement that the indexes must be the same.  Without altering the data structure that you now have, this additional structure provides an index into it.

Comment: Hi Mike, about your first comment: first, thanks. Since the increment exists, a key is always possible, but it might the key 8, or 9 etc.

Comment: Hi Mike, about your second comment: i will figure something out. Thanks!

Comment: Something along the lines of: `array_push($inverted[$key], array($sku, $location));` . . . Now, you know every key that exists anywhere, and everywhere that the key may be found.